# How do i provide a custom session ID getter/setter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to pass the sessionID as a json parameter, I can see how to override SessionIDManager and such, but this just covers custom creation/validation of sessionID's as opposed to where it actually gets the sessionID from.

There is of course 'cookieless' which puts it in the url, but that doesn't work for me either.

So i'd like to override the session handling so I can specify where it should look for the sessionID.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx